# Avoid Flickering with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

In the context of a Java Rubik's Cube application I am trying to animate the cube actions performed by the end user.

To do that I am just using rotations and many redraws as following:

```
GL11.glRotatef(zRotate, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

the zRotate variable is icremented from 0 to 90 and I am performing redraws every 20 miliseconds.

It works perfectly but I see flickering on the screen .. How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the SWT.NO_BACKGROUND style in the Opengl canvas creation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=2636.0), You could call `Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);` during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Use Double buffering.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_buffer#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics

I dont have any experience with LWJGL, but a common technique is to draw into a bitmap and to redraw the screen/window with the bitmap in one step.

Comment: Without vsync this could also give flickering.

Comment: LWJGL work by default with double buffering, so you don't have to worry about this. (http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=1187.0)